# Python threading with streaming as for loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, streaming, python-multithreading

My streaming algorith looks something like this

```
queue = stream.request
for item in queue:
    if item == what_i_am_looking_for:
        output=open_webpage()
        send_message(output)
```

Both the for loop and the open_webpage() involve waiting for i/o, be it from the stream I'm waiting for or a webpage I want to load. Problem is opening a webpage can take a lot of time, causing me to get behind on the queue for my stream.

This seems like the perfect candidate for threading to me, which I learned about recently. But how can I implement it? What I tried was making something that looks like this:

```
queue = stream.request
for item in queue:
    if item == what_i_am_looking_for:
        found_item_thread=Thread(target=open_webpage_and_send)
        found_item_thread.start
        found_item_thread.join
```

But it doesn't work like I want it to. What I would like to happen is for the program to continuously load the new streaming items in the queue. Then, when an item I'm looking for is found, it continues to load the queue of the stream, but as a thread while that is happening loads the webpage too.

edit: @abdusco So using a ThreadPoolExecutor, would my pseudocode look something like this?

```
def stream():
    queue = stream.request
    for item in queue:
        if item == what_i_am_looking_for:
            open_webpage=executor.submit(open_webpage)

def main():
    ThreadPoolExecutor as executor:
    stream=executor.submit(stream)
```

Comment: You could make your open_webpage() function async and not not await for it then you do output = ....

Comment: @m0bi5 I don't know anything about async functions. Could you give an example of how it could be implemented? Does it work like threading?

Comment: Logically it is very similar to threading, have a look at this - https://realpython.com/async-io-python/

Comment: Check out ThreadPoolExecutor. https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example

Comment: @m0bi5 Okay after looking at asynchio a bit I think I understand basically how it works. Are you suggesting I change the output=... line to a task? As in output=asynchio.create_task(open_webpage())? With both the open_webpage function and the function this code is in being preceeded by "async"?

Comment: @abdusco it seems to me that ThreadPoolExecutor is a way of executing many threads at the same time. Do I have that right? So in the example it loads a bunch of urls at once using threading. That's a bit different from what I'm looking for, or at least it's not clear to me how to use that. Basically what I'm looking for is a way to call a thread (or thread like process) from within a for loop, then have that thread execute during downtime between the entries in the for loop.

Comment: You start a thread pool in another thread, and share a queue to its of workers, which then pull work items off of that queue, while you fill the queue on the main thread. Search for `python multiple producer consumer`

Comment: @abdusco is the pseudocode in my edit what you are trying to describe? That's what makes sense to me after a little searching. Though shouldn't there be a thread.join command somewhere? I'm not sure where that would go here

Comment: @m0bi5 I make a version of my code using async (which took a while because unfortunately it's much more complicated than my pseudocode). What seems to be happening if if I create a task it will not execute at all unless I await it. Which basically defeats the purpose. If I await the task it simply works like it did originally, but if I don't it doesn't seem to execute at all.

Comment: @SSCFan you will be able to execute the task without awaiting it. That is the default behavior of create_task(). Are you sure it is not getting executed?And yes, I think you understood correctly the open_webpage should be async def...

Comment: @SSCFan actually I think another way will work, check my answer and try it out

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use asyncio and create a background task as follows -

```
import asyncio

async def my_task():
    output=open_webpage()
    await send_message(output)

queue = stream.request 
for item in queue:
    if item == what_i_am_looking_for:
        #Task will run in the background, for loop will keep running
        asyncio.create_task(my_task())
```